# HTTPS for localhost for Django development with stunnel

Tags: python, django, web, https, stunnel

I'm working through the book "Django 2 by example".

The second excercise creates a bookmarklet launcher, which loads some javascript from the local Django folder. Testing with a/the recent Firefox version (I'm using arch linux by the way), means that a HTTPS connection is required and I'm having trouble with setting this up.

For this I set up stunnel, however it doesn't seem to work fully:

- The bookmarklet loads correctly on the website that I'm developing,
- however on all other sites I'm getting `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://127.0.0.1:8443/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=797695449745”.` message in the FF web dev console.

The book recommends ngrok, however I don't feel comfortable relying on a third party for these simple tests nor do I feel comfortable necessarily exposing my laptop to the whole web. Hence my efforts with stunnel.

While I'm on the webpage I'm developing (https://127.0.0.1:8443/account/#), FF complains about the connection not being secure when checking where usually the green lock is, though the site loads.

```
# dev_https
pid=                                                                                                                                                                                                        

cert = stunnel/stunnel.pem                                                                                                                                                                                  
key = stunnel/stunnel.key                                                                                                                                                                                   

options=NO_SSLv3                                                                                                                                                                                            
foreground = yes                                                                                                                                                                                            
output = stunnel.log                                                                                                                                                                                        
debug = 7                                                                                                                                                                                                   
output = stunnel.log                                                                                                                                                                                        

[https]                                                                                                                                                                                                     
accept=127.0.0.1:8443                                                                                                                                                                                       
connect=127.0.0.1:8001     
TIMEOUTclose=1
```

and started with

`stunnel dev_https`.

The Django development server is started with

`HTTPS=1 python manage.py runserver 8001`

What changes can I make so that the bookmarklet will load the code on any site?

Comment: "Testing with a/the recent Firefox version (I'm using arch linux by the way), means that a HTTPS connection is required." Even for `localhost`?

Comment: @Chris, it is for `127.0.0.1`.... not sure why this is not trusted... or maybe there is a setting?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe there are different rules for bookmarklets. But most browsers relax their "require SSL" rules for `localhost`, e.g. to do geolocation or similar.